# Alternatives to realize Excel button on ipad

Tags: excel, vba, ipad

I realized a "+" button via excel vba. If the user clicks on the button, a counter variable in another cell is incremented.

I am aware that macros are not supported on mobile versions of excel, so I am looking for alternatives, e.g. a different software, to execute my calculation on an ipad.

My program resembles a small "cash" system: Given a moderate number of rows with items, I want to offer a "+" and a "-" button that increment/decrement a corresponding counter variable. Finally, I multiply the counted observations with a price and sum them up. Optionally, there is a "clear" button to reset the counted observations to zero.

Are there tools/software to write such a program that works on ipad?

Comment: Likely you'd need to use office script - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel